# Unable to get index of array

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vuejs2

I am trying to get the current index of an array when using v-for like so:

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in timetable">
    Index: @{{index}}

    <td>@{{ item.subject }}</td>
    <div v-if="index == timetable.length - 1">
        <td>@{{ item.lesson_end }}</td>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
        <td>@{{ item.lesson_start }}</td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

But I only get the error message:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Why does it claim that index is not defined, according the docs this should be valid?

Comment: share sample of your data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solely due to your invalid HTML structure. Vue's `render` function is not able to interpolate the result correctly and thus, you get that error.

Try something like

```html
<tr v-for="(item,index) in timetable">
  <td>Index: @{{ index }}</td>
  <td>@{{ item.subject }}</td>
  <td v-if="index == timetable.length - 1">@{{ item.lesson_end }}</td>
  <td v-else>@{{ item.lesson_start }}</td>
</tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrvdjxpq/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the problem. So the divs are creating issues?

Comment: Nice find, I just finished my jsfiddle with the same solution but you were faster :P

Comment: @Araw And the `Index: @{{index}}` text on its own. The only content within a `<tr>` should be `<td>` and / or `<th>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Comment: Oh, I see :)
Thanks again!